# How to create a dataframe whose name is stored in a vector

Tags: r, dynamic, dataframe, naming, read.csv

I have to run a R script every month, it read a .csv file into a **dataframe** and perform some manipulations on it.

The name of this **dataframe** needs to be dynamic for example:
**df_jan** for **January**, **df_feb** for February and so on

I have created a character vector which contains the required data frame name using *paste()* function and *Sys.Date()* function

I want to automate this code therefore I don't want to rename this dataframe everytime I run this script

Now, how do I read the .csv into this data frame.
Currently I'm loading the file into a dataframe - **'df'** and using the *assign()* function to assign it the required name, Is there any better method to accomplish the same?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of reading in the csv to a data.frame first and then using assign, you could do it all in one call. I.e. `assign("df_jan",read.csv(...))`

Comment: Yes, but the thing is this dataframe won't exist , the name 'df_jan' is stored in a dynamically created vector using Sys.Date and paste function.

I want to read the .csv file into a dataframe whose name will change every month depending on the current month

Comment: It is unclear why you believe you need to change the name of the data.frame in your code. That makes it hard to suggest better alternatives (because you don't need to do that).

Comment: @Roland This is a legacy code which requires the particular dataframe name throughout the code, 
Currently we need to rename the dataframe everymonth which reads in the .csv file, I'm trying to automate this process

Comment: How does this require a specific data.frame name? R really doesn't care how you name your objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
create.df <- function(path){
        assign(paste0("df_", format(Sys.Date(), "%b")),
               read.csv(path),
               envir = .GlobalEnv
               )
}
```

then call `create.df` with path to your `.csv`

Comment: Don't do this. Instead of creating several automatically created dynamically named data.frames in the global environment, you should just put them together into a list.

Comment: And how do i refer to these dataframes in the code, for example while assigning colnames using the colnames(df) function what will i pass in the parameters?

Comment: @Vaibhav If you do this you land in a hellish place where you have to use complicated `assign` and `get` expressions everywhere or, the better option, have to use `.GlobalEnv[[name]]` to refer to the object. Why would you want that?

Comment: Yeah I think using a constant dataframe name will be better, I might have to spend sometime modifying the entire code but it will be better in the long run
Thanks for the help guys
Btw what does .GlobalEnv[[name]] do ?

Comment: You can reference objects in an environment with `[[`. See `help("[["")`.